# How to link to a website via ListView Item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I got a List View filled from an Array List with changing items. So I don't know any positions.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
listview1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I would like to click on an item and be linked Go google pictures with the item as the search word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply implement ***OnItemClickListener()*** for listView.

Like:

```
yourlistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Here arg2 is a Postion
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list is array of Urls then try like this,

```
public class SampleListActivity extends ListActivity {

static final String[] URLS = new String[] { "http://music.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://etc.com","http://etc1.com","http://etc2.com"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.yourlayout,
            URLS));

    final ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String selectedUrl= URLS[position];
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(selectedUrl);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open a webpage with this.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thx, your solution plus @Piyush Gupta solution helped me a lot